# Exception thrown in OneTimeTearDown; Tests not marked as failure

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

Title says it all ...

- I'm working in C#, in Visual Studio, with NUnit, and with ReSharper as my TestRunner
- I have a unit test with a `[OneTimeTearDown]` method.
- That method is throwing an exception at the moment.
- The test appears to be marked as 'inconclusive', rather than failed.

This seems a bit rubbish :(
Is there a way to fix this, or is it just how the framework works?

Answer (score 0):

It's a combination of how the framework works and how the runner is reporting the result. At the point in time when `OneTimeTearDown` fails, all the tests have already been reported to the runner as succeeding, through test completion events.

So, those tests did run successfully but something went wrong in cleaning up the fixture. That error is reported against the fixture. Some runners may show this information and some may not. If you are running under the Test Explorer in Visual Studio, you'll notice that there is no info shown for fixtures, only for individual tests. So the runner, if it wants to report the failure to you, has no place to do it except possibly as text in the output window.

As an experiment, you might try running your tests under `nunit3-console` to see how it handles the result. You could also try using the NUnit 3 VS adapter **without** ReSharper to see how that comes out. Then pick the approach you like best and/or file an issue with the developers of the particular runner.

PS: If you run under `nunit3-console`, you can examine the XML result file to see what info is reported to any runner.

Sorry that this is not a more immediately useful answer!

Answer (score 0):

This 'feature' can cause an Azure Pipeline to timeout if an exception is thrown in [OneTimeTearDown]

If running WebDriver tests, put nothing more than driver.Quit() in [OneTimeTearDown]

```
[OneTimeTearDown]
public void OneTimeTeardown()
{
    driver.Quit();
}
```